# Use append element as "this" - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML and jQuery code:

HTML

```
<div id="overlay">
    <button onclick="startEdit()" class="edit_button">Start Editing</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".product").click(function() {
    var imageName = $(this).data("image");
    console.log(imageName);
    var imageItem = $("#overlay").append("<div class='product-container'><img class='product-image' src='" + imageName + ".png'></div>");

    var ele = imageItem;

    ele.draggable({});
    // (Theres more than this, but this explains what I'm trying to do)
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to use the appended element, in this case what is assigned to `imageItem` (`div.product-container`), further down the code.

What do I need to do to be able to use it similar to `$(this)` as I need to run some code further down that applies to that specific element.

Comment: Can't you simply select $('.product-container') or give it a unique id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm trying to achieve is to use the appended element, in this case what is assigned to `imageItem` (`div.product-container`), further down the code.

But that's not what's assigned to `imageItem`; `imageItem` contains the `#overlay` element.

Instead:

```
var imageItem = $("<div class='product-container'><img class='product-image' src='" + imageName + ".png'></div>");
$("#overlay").append(imageItem);
// Or:
// imageItem.appendTo("#overlay");
```

Now `imageItem` contains the `div.product-container` and you can use it elsewhere.

Comment: Beautiful! Great answer, I had a feeling I could do it with a variable, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same is to use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
var imageItem = $("<div class='product-container'><img class='product-image' src='" + imageName + ".png'></div>").appendTo('#overlay');
```